# Macro to autofill a cell based on a value in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a hard time trying to find a macro for the following use:

Taking in consideration this example:

[image]

Consider that i have in the "sheet 1" the table with the columns Country and Food with its values.

In the sheet 2, i have two columns named Country#1 and Food#1. The macro i want, needs to autofill the Food#1 cell that is associated with the right text in Country#1 cell, via the drop down list.

Example: When i select "Madrid" in Country#1, it needs to autofill the Food#1 with the text "Tapas and tortillas".

I'm sorry if this is a re-post question, but i didn't saw anything close as this :|

Best regards,
Luís

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Sheet Change Event like below...

The following code assumes that you have a list of Countries and their food in column A and B respectively on Sheet1 and the country dropdown list is in column A on Sheet2.

Right click the Sheet2 Tab --> View code --> Past the following code into the opened code window.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim r As Long
Set wsSource = Sheets("Sheet1")     'Source sheet which contains a table of countries and their food
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    If Application.CountIf(wsSource.Columns(1), Target.Value) > 0 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        r = Application.Match(Target.Value, wsSource.Columns(1), 0)
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = wsSource.Cells(r, 2)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I'm sorry to bothering you, but this code can be scaled in a way that i can autofill more than 1 column? For example, instead of just filling the column Food#1 in the Sheet2, it fill column Toys#1,Dessert#1, Main#1 and Dish#1(all of these are already on Sheet1, like the example in the main question)?

Comment: @Luís Please open a new question and share the screenshot of your data and the code you are currently using and describing what it does for you so that other members can also look at it.